# Material UI Base useAutocomplete getOptionLabel usage

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to implement an autocomplete component using Material Base UI's [useAutocomplete](https://mui.com/base-ui/react-autocomplete/hooks-api/) hook.  I want to support a custom `options` structure.  I am unsure how to use the `getOptionLabel` function in this component to access the property I am trying to display.

Their initial [example](https://mui.com/base-ui/react-autocomplete/#introduction) manually grabs `option.label` when rendering its `<StyledOption>`.

Their [example](https://mui.com/base-ui/react-autocomplete/#rendering-options) discussing custom options structure shows providing `getOptionLabel` as a prop to the `useAutocomplete` call, but does not specify how I am supposed to access the desired option properties as labels in the markup.

I am trying to create an autocomplete component that will support multiple options structures, and so my hope was to rely on the caller passing `getOptionLabel` per the specific type of options it will be providing.

```
// parent component
const options = [ { foo: "a label" }, { foo: "another label" } ]
<MyAutocomplete
  options={options}
  getOptionLabel={(option) => option.foo}
/>
```

Thanks!

Comment: can you share your `MyAutocomplete` component. Also try their [example](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/#useautocomplete)

Comment: My component is basically a copy of the example in the docs, I think the answer below touches on the question of "where am I supposed to invoke `getOptionLabel`"

Answer (score 1):

You say the:

> custom options structure [example] [...] does not specify how I am supposed to access the desired option properties as labels in the markup.

The example is not there to specify *how*. It specifies that the data type of the return value of the **getOptionLabel** function must be a (unique) string. Your software project somehow will allow an end user developer to provide the function. It is the end user developer that specifies the *how*. You just need to tell them that their function receives an *option* as an argument, and must return a *string* unique to each option (the updated code below informs about the argument and return data type with the `OptionLabelGetter` interface in `app.tsx`). You assign the function to **getOptionLabel** (in `app.tsx`).

Assuming the end user developer provides the **getOptionLabel** function as a prop named `labelGetter` (you see this in `main.tsx` below), the [initial example](https://mui.com/base-ui/react-autocomplete/#introduction) from the MUI documentation could be updated to this (`app.tsx` below):

(To see exactly what was changed, view the changes to `app.tsx` as a diff using the [timeline option](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77619437/timeline) on this answer (ignore the diff on main.tsx). On the timeline, select the triangle link near "edited", at the first edit, to expand the page to see where the changes occurred.)

## Updated code

`main.tsx` and `index.html` are samples of code written by the end user developer. `main.tsx` and `app.tsx` are to be compiled to a bundle named `main.js`.

### app.tsx

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { useAutocomplete, UseAutocompleteProps } from '@mui/base/useAutocomplete';
import { Button } from '@mui/base/Button';
import { Popper } from '@mui/base/Popper';
import { styled } from '@mui/system';
import { unstable_useForkRef as useForkRef } from '@mui/utils';
import ArrowDropDownIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ArrowDropDown';
import ClearIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Clear';

export interface OptionLabelGetter<Type> {
    ( option: Type ): string; 
}

interface AutocompleteIntroductionProps<Type> {
    labelGetter: OptionLabelGetter<Type>;   
    options: Type[];
}

type ExtendedAutocompleteProps = UseAutocompleteProps<any, false, false, false> & AutocompleteIntroductionProps<any>;

const Autocomplete = React.forwardRef(function Autocomplete(
  props: ExtendedAutocompleteProps,
  ref: React.ForwardedRef<HTMLDivElement>,
) {
  const {
    disableClearable = false,
    disabled = false,
    readOnly = false,
    labelGetter,
    ...other
  } = props;

  const {
    getRootProps,
    getInputProps,
    getPopupIndicatorProps,
    getClearProps,
    getListboxProps,
    getOptionProps,
    dirty,
    id,
    popupOpen,
    focused,
    anchorEl,
    setAnchorEl,
    groupedOptions,
  } = useAutocomplete({
    ...props,
    componentName: 'BaseAutocompleteIntroduction',
    getOptionLabel: labelGetter
  });

  const hasClearIcon = !disableClearable && !disabled && dirty && !readOnly;

  const rootRef = useForkRef(ref, setAnchorEl);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <StyledAutocompleteRoot
        {...getRootProps(other)}
        ref={rootRef}
        className={focused ? 'focused' : undefined}
      >
        <StyledInput
          id={id}
          disabled={disabled}
          readOnly={readOnly}
          {...getInputProps()}
        />
        {hasClearIcon && (
          <StyledClearIndicator {...getClearProps()}>
            <ClearIcon />
          </StyledClearIndicator>
        )}
        <StyledPopupIndicator
          {...getPopupIndicatorProps()}
          className={popupOpen ? 'popupOpen' : undefined}
        >
          <ArrowDropDownIcon />
        </StyledPopupIndicator>
      </StyledAutocompleteRoot>
      {anchorEl ? (
        <Popper
          open={popupOpen}
          anchorEl={anchorEl}
          slots={{
            root: StyledPopper,
          }}
          modifiers={[
            { name: 'flip', enabled: false },
            { name: 'preventOverflow', enabled: false },
          ]}
        >
          <StyledListbox {...getListboxProps()}>
            {(groupedOptions as any[]).map((option: any, index) => {
              const optionProps = getOptionProps({ option, index });

              return <StyledOption {...optionProps}>{ labelGetter( option ) }</StyledOption>;
            })}

            {groupedOptions.length === 0 && (
              <StyledNoOptions>No results</StyledNoOptions>
            )}
          </StyledListbox>
        </Popper>
      ) : null}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
});

export default function AutocompleteIntroduction( props: ExtendedAutocompleteProps ) {
  return <Autocomplete { ...props } />;
}

const blue = {
  100: '#DAECFF',
  200: '#99CCF3',
  400: '#3399FF',
  500: '#007FFF',
  600: '#0072E5',
  700: '#0059B2',
  900: '#003A75',
};

const grey = {
  50: '#F3F6F9',
  100: '#E5EAF2',
  200: '#DAE2ED',
  300: '#C7D0DD',
  400: '#B0B8C4',
  500: '#9DA8B7',
  600: '#6B7A90',
  700: '#434D5B',
  800: '#303740',
  900: '#1C2025',
};

const StyledAutocompleteRoot = styled('div')(
  ({ theme }) => `
  font-family: 'IBM Plex Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  border-radius: 8px;
  color: ${theme.palette.mode === 'dark' ? grey[300] : grey[500]};
  background: ${theme.palette.mode === 'dark' ? grey[900] : '#fff'};
  border: 1px solid ${theme.palette.mode === 'dark' ? grey[700] : grey[200]};
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px ${
    theme.palette.mode === 'dark' ? 'rgba(0,0,0, 0.5)' : 'rgba(0,0,0, 0.05)'
  };
  display: flex;
  gap: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 320px;

  &.focused {
    border-color: ${blue[400]};
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px ${theme.palette.mode === 'dark' ? blue[700] : blue[200]};
  }

  &:hover {
    background: ${theme.palette.mode === 'dark' ? grey[800] : grey[50]};
    border-color: ${theme.palette.mode === 'dark' ? grey[600] : grey[300]};
  }

  &:focus-visible {
    outline: 0;
  }
`,
);

const StyledInput = styled('input')(
  ({ theme }) => `
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: ${theme.palette.mode === 'dark' ? grey[300] : grey[900]};
  background: inherit;
  border: none;
  border-radius: inherit;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  outline: 0;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
`,
);

// ComponentPageTabs has z-index: 1000
const StyledPopper = styled('div')`
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1001;
  width: 320px;
`;

const StyledListbox = styled('ul')(
  ({ theme }) => `
  font-family: 'IBM Plex Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 6px;
  margin: 12px 0;
  min-width: 320px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  overflow: auto;
  outline: 0px;
  max-height: 300px;
  z-index: 1;
  background: ${theme.palette.mode === 'dark' ? grey[900] : '#fff'};
  border: 1px solid ${theme.palette.mode === 'dark' ? grey[700] : grey[200]};
  color: ${theme.palette.mode === 'dark' ? grey[300] : grey[900]};
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 6px ${
    theme.palette.mode === 'dark' ? 'rgba(0,0,0, 0.3)' : 'rgba(0,0,0, 0.05)'
  };
  `,
);

const StyledOption = styled('li')(
  ({ theme }) => `
  list-style: none;
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  cursor: default;

  &:last-of-type {
    border-bottom: none;
  }

  &:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  &[aria-selected=true] {
    background-color: ${theme.palette.mode === 'dark' ? blue[900] : blue[100]};
    color: ${theme.palette.mode === 'dark' ? blue[100] : blue[900]};
  }

  &.Mui-focused,
  &.Mui-focusVisible {
    background-color: ${theme.palette.mode === 'dark' ? grey[800] : grey[100]};
    color: ${theme.palette.mode === 'dark' ? grey[300] : grey[900]};
  }

  &.Mui-focusVisible {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px ${theme.palette.mode === 'dark' ? blue[500] : blue[200]};
  }

  &[aria-selected=true].Mui-focused,
  &[aria-selected=true].Mui-focusVisible {
    background-color: ${theme.palette.mode === 'dark' ? blue[900] : blue[100]};
    color: ${theme.palette.mode === 'dark' ? blue[100] : blue[900]};
  }
  `,
);

const StyledPopupIndicator = styled(Button)(
  ({ theme }) => `
    outline: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: transparent;
    align-self: center;
    padding: 0 2px;

    &:hover {
      background-color: ${theme.palette.mode === 'dark' ? grey[700] : blue[100]};
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    & > svg {
      transform: translateY(2px);
    }

    &.popupOpen > svg {
      transform: translateY(2px) rotate(180deg);
    }
  `,
);

const StyledClearIndicator = styled(Button)(
  ({ theme }) => `
    outline: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: transparent;
    align-self: center;
    padding: 0 2px;

    &:hover {
      background-color: ${theme.palette.mode === 'dark' ? grey[700] : blue[100]};
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    & > svg {
      transform: translateY(2px) scale(0.9);
    }
  `,
);

const StyledNoOptions = styled('li')`
  list-style: none;
  padding: 8px;
  cursor: default;
`;
```

### main.tsx

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';
import App, { OptionLabelGetter } from './app';

export interface CustomOption {
    identifier: string;
    year: number;
}

const top100Films: CustomOption[] = [
    { identifier: 'The Shawshank Redemption', year: 1994 },
    { identifier: 'The Godfather', year: 1972 },
    { identifier: 'The Godfather: Part II', year: 1974 },
    { identifier: 'The Dark Knight', year: 2008 },
    { identifier: '12 Angry Men', year: 1957 },
    { identifier: "Schindler's List", year: 1993 },
    { identifier: 'Pulp Fiction', year: 1994 },
    {
      identifier: 'The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King',
      year: 2003,
    },
    { identifier: 'The Good, the Bad and the Ugly', year: 1966 },
    { identifier: 'Fight Club', year: 1999 },
    {
      identifier: 'The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring',
      year: 2001,
    },
    {
      identifier: 'Star Wars: Episode V - The Empire Strikes Back',
      year: 1980,
    },
    { identifier: 'Forrest Gump', year: 1994 },
    { identifier: 'Inception', year: 2010 },
    {
      identifier: 'The Lord of the Rings: The Two Towers',
      year: 2002,
    },
    { identifier: "One Flew Over the Cuckoo's Nest", year: 1975 },
    { identifier: 'Goodfellas', year: 1990 },
    { identifier: 'The Matrix', year: 1999 },
    { identifier: 'Seven Samurai', year: 1954 },
    {
      identifier: 'Star Wars: Episode IV - A New Hope',
      year: 1977,
    },
    { identifier: 'City of God', year: 2002 },
    { identifier: 'Se7en', year: 1995 },
    { identifier: 'The Silence of the Lambs', year: 1991 },
    { identifier: "It's a Wonderful Life", year: 1946 },
    { identifier: 'Life Is Beautiful', year: 1997 },
    { identifier: 'The Usual Suspects', year: 1995 },
    { identifier: 'Léon: The Professional', year: 1994 },
    { identifier: 'Spirited Away', year: 2001 },
    { identifier: 'Saving Private Ryan', year: 1998 },
    { identifier: 'Once Upon a Time in the West', year: 1968 },
    { identifier: 'American History X', year: 1998 },
    { identifier: 'Interstellar', year: 2014 },
    { identifier: 'Casablanca', year: 1942 },
    { identifier: 'City Lights', year: 1931 },
    { identifier: 'Psycho', year: 1960 },
    { identifier: 'The Green Mile', year: 1999 },
    { identifier: 'The Intouchables', year: 2011 },
    { identifier: 'Modern Times', year: 1936 },
    { identifier: 'Raiders of the Lost Ark', year: 1981 },
    { identifier: 'Rear Window', year: 1954 },
    { identifier: 'The Pianist', year: 2002 },
    { identifier: 'The Departed', year: 2006 },
    { identifier: 'Terminator 2: Judgment Day', year: 1991 },
    { identifier: 'Back to the Future', year: 1985 },
    { identifier: 'Whiplash', year: 2014 },
    { identifier: 'Gladiator', year: 2000 },
    { identifier: 'Memento', year: 2000 },
    { identifier: 'The Prestige', year: 2006 },
    { identifier: 'The Lion King', year: 1994 },
    { identifier: 'Apocalypse Now', year: 1979 },
    { identifier: 'Alien', year: 1979 },
    { identifier: 'Sunset Boulevard', year: 1950 },
    {
      identifier: 'Dr. Strangelove or: How I Learned to Stop Worrying and Love the Bomb',
      year: 1964,
    },
    { identifier: 'The Great Dictator', year: 1940 },
    { identifier: 'Cinema Paradiso', year: 1988 },
    { identifier: 'The Lives of Others', year: 2006 },
    { identifier: 'Grave of the Fireflies', year: 1988 },
    { identifier: 'Paths of Glory', year: 1957 },
    { identifier: 'Django Unchained', year: 2012 },
    { identifier: 'The Shining', year: 1980 },
    { identifier: 'WALL·E', year: 2008 },
    { identifier: 'American Beauty', year: 1999 },
    { identifier: 'The Dark Knight Rises', year: 2012 },
    { identifier: 'Princess Mononoke', year: 1997 },
    { identifier: 'Aliens', year: 1986 },
    { identifier: 'Oldboy', year: 2003 },
    { identifier: 'Once Upon a Time in America', year: 1984 },
    { identifier: 'Witness for the Prosecution', year: 1957 },
    { identifier: 'Das Boot', year: 1981 },
    { identifier: 'Citizen Kane', year: 1941 },
    { identifier: 'North by Northwest', year: 1959 },
    { identifier: 'Vertigo', year: 1958 },
    {
      identifier: 'Star Wars: Episode VI - Return of the Jedi',
      year: 1983,
    },
    { identifier: 'Reservoir Dogs', year: 1992 },
    { identifier: 'Braveheart', year: 1995 },
    { identifier: 'M', year: 1931 },
    { identifier: 'Requiem for a Dream', year: 2000 },
    { identifier: 'Amélie', year: 2001 },
    { identifier: 'A Clockwork Orange', year: 1971 },
    { identifier: 'Like Stars on Earth', year: 2007 },
    { identifier: 'Taxi Driver', year: 1976 },
    { identifier: 'Lawrence of Arabia', year: 1962 },
    { identifier: 'Double Indemnity', year: 1944 },
    {
      identifier: 'Eternal Sunshine of the Spotless Mind',
      year: 2004,
    },
    { identifier: 'Amadeus', year: 1984 },
    { identifier: 'To Kill a Mockingbird', year: 1962 },
    { identifier: 'Toy Story 3', year: 2010 },
    { identifier: 'Logan', year: 2017 },
    { identifier: 'Full Metal Jacket', year: 1987 },
    { identifier: 'Dangal', year: 2016 },
    { identifier: 'The Sting', year: 1973 },
    { identifier: '2001: A Space Odyssey', year: 1968 },
    { identifier: "Singin' in the Rain", year: 1952 },
    { identifier: 'Toy Story', year: 1995 },
    { identifier: 'Bicycle Thieves', year: 1948 },
    { identifier: 'The Kid', year: 1921 },
    { identifier: 'Inglourious Basterds', year: 2009 },
    { identifier: 'Snatch', year: 2000 },
    { identifier: '3 Idiots', year: 2009 },
    { identifier: 'Monty Python and the Holy Grail', year: 1975 },
];

const MyCustomOptionLabelGetter: OptionLabelGetter<CustomOption> = ( option: CustomOption ): string => option.identifier;

const container = document.getElementById( 'container' );

let root;
if ( container != null ) {
    root = createRoot( container );
} else {
    throw new Error( 'Missing container element.' );
}

const theme = createTheme();

root.render(
    <ThemeProvider theme={ theme }>
        <App
            labelGetter={ MyCustomOptionLabelGetter }
            options={ top100Films }
        />
    </ThemeProvider>
);
```

### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>MUI useAutocomplete Example</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="data:;">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=1">
        <script defer src="main.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container"></div>
        <noscript> Please enable javascript to view the site </noscript>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Makes sense - I see you had to type your `UseAutocompleteProps` with `any` - I think in my case I was hoping to provide `UseAutocompleteProps` with a union type consisting of every supported option structure (which was then causing a headache in my `labelGetter` functions, as they all had to deal with every possible option shape)

Comment: There could be another approach. But, I just figured that the *option* object shape is arbitrary. It could be almost anything. One hard rule is that *labelGetter* has to return a (unique) string from that option.

Comment: Right, yea I guess I'm trying to avoid something like `if (option.someProp)` `else if (option.someOtherProp)` - there is a disconnect between the autocomplete component (which accepts a variety of option shapes) and the parent, who defines the `labelGetter` (which knows _which_ specific option shape it wants to deal with).  So TypeScript is unhappy with accessing props that may or may not exist on the option type in the `labelGetter` functions

Comment: I see. Since the end user developer is the author/provider of the *option* object and the consumer of this same object, there might not be anything that can be done about it. It will be the author's responsibility to write a *labelGetter* that accesses properties that are guaranteed to exist on their own *CustomOption*. There are a few Autocomplete props that use **option** in their handlers/callbacks. You might need to use other Typescript interfaces and require other callbacks from the developer to handle things like comparators for *option* and *value*.