# Material UI Base - useAutocomplete Hook with a variety of option shapes?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, react-typescript

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77617015/material-ui-base-useautocomplete-getoptionlabel-usage) I asked about *where* to invoke the `getOptionLabel` function.

A follow-up question is this:

Suppose I am trying to create an autocomplete component that supports a variety of option shapes:

```
export type AutocompleteOption = {
    id?: number;
    label: string;
} | {
    foo: number;
    bar: boolean;
    baz: string;
} | string | number;
```

Satisfying TypeScript in my `getOptionLabel` functions is then rather difficult.  Architecturally, while any specific parent of the autocomplete component will likely be dealing with 1 of the above prop shapes (and will know which shape it is dealing with), the function signature for `getOptionLabel` will be unable to tell *which* option shape we have.

So a parent that passes `{ id, label }` as options will have to create a `getOptionLabel` function that still deals with the other possible option shapes.

```
getOptionLabel={(option: AutocompleteOption) => {
    if (typeof option === "string") return option  // <-- !!!
    else if (option.label) return option.label
    else if (option.bar) return option.bar // <-- !!!
}}
```

So now I'm wondering... is the architecture of MUI Base useAutocomplete just not really conducive to supporting several option shapes / types in the same component?